# session destroy in log-in and disable back

Tags: php, html, mysql, session, session-variables

I have 4 files home.php, log_out.php, blank_one.php, connection.php
and did not include the login.php and index.php since it only reads the 
user name and password.

My problem is the session after clicking the log out

> then click arrow back

to go **blank_one.php** directly I get these errors :'(

- **Notice: Undefined index: CurrentUser**
- **Notice: Undefined index: CurrentUserType**
- BLANK ONE

========================================================================

and since logout(log_out.php) was clicked the content must be **no user found** ,EMPTY and back should be disabled.

Is there a way to handle this sessions to remove the errors after destroying it ?

`help please. :'(

blank_one.php

```html
    <?php
    session_start();
    $currUser = $_SESSION["CurrentUser"];
    $currUserType = $_SESSION["CurrentUserType"];
    echo('BLANK ONE');
    ?>
```

home.php

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 $currUser = $_SESSION["CurrentUser"];
 $currUserType = $_SESSION["CurrentUserType"];
 if($currUserType == '1' or $currUserType == '2') 
 {
  echo '
        <html>
        <body>
        <a href="blank_one.php">blank</a>
        <a href="log_out.php">logout</a>
        
        </body>
        </html>
        ';
   
 }
 
 else if($currUserType == '2'){
 
 }
 
 else if($currUserType == '3'){
  echo '
  
  ';
  
 }else{
  echo '<div> no user found </div>';
      

 }
  
?>
```

connection.php

```html
  <?php
  $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'life');

   if (!$conn) 
   {
    die('Connect Error: ' . mysql_errno());
                session_destroy();
                session_start();
   }
   
            else
   {
    //echo ("connected from connection.php");
                session_start();
    echo ("");
   }
  ?>
```

log_out.php

```html
  <?php
  session_start();
  include('connection.php');
  $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'wildlife');
  
  if ($conn) 
  {
   $update=mysql_query("INSERT INTO wrd_user(emp_log_out)  VALUES (now())");
  session_destroy();
  mysql_close();
   header('Location:index.php');
  }
  else
   {
    
    echo ("");
   }
   
   
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your variable setting code in blank_one.php will solve the problem:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION["CurrentUser"])) {
    $currUser = $_SESSION["CurrentUser"];
}
if (isset($_SESSION["CurrentUserType"])) {
    $currUserType = $_SESSION["CurrentUserType"];
}
echo('BLANK ONE');
?>
```

You need the same in home.php too.

Comment: HI<?php
 session_start();
 //$currUser = $_SESSION["CurrentUser"];
 //$currUserType = $_SESSION["CurrentUserType"];
    if (isset($_SESSION["CurrentUser"])) 
    {
        $currUser = $_SESSION["CurrentUser"];
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION["CurrentUserType"])) 
    {
        $currUserType = $_SESSION["CurrentUserType"];
    }

 if($currUserType == '1' or $currUserType == '2') 
 {

Comment: If you use them separate then yes, if use them bonded together, so you can check them with a single if statement too. Please use code formatting in your comment. You can write code into your comment after a new line and 4 spaces.

Comment: Sorry,about the code formatting. Thankyou for the help. I will try it.

Comment: THANKYOUU IT WORKEDD :)

Answer (score 1):

You should test if the session variables (created with the login page) are set to verify that the user is logged in or not.

**blank_one.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
if( (isset($_SESSION['CurrentUser']) &&(isset($_SESSION['CurrentUserType'])) {
    $currUser = $_SESSION["CurrentUser"];
    $currUserType = $_SESSION["CurrentUserType"];
}
else {
    echo('BLANK ONE');
}
?>
```

This should be done also in the protected pages so as to avoid errors and security problems with direct URL access when the user is not logged in. And the user should be redirected in that case.

**home.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
        if( (isset($_SESSION['CurrentUser']) &&(isset($_SESSION['CurrentUserType'])) {
        $currUser = $_SESSION["CurrentUser"];
        $currUserType = $_SESSION["CurrentUserType"];
        }
        else
        {
            header('Location:index.php');
            die();
        }
    if($currUserType == '1' or $currUserType == '2')    
    {
        echo '
        <html>
        <body>
        <a href="blank_one.php">blank</a>
        <a href="log_out.php">logout</a>

        </body>
        </html>
        ';

    }

    else if($currUserType == '2'){

    }

    else if($currUserType == '3'){
        echo '

        ';

    }else{
        echo '<div> no user found </div>';
    }
?>
```